# Connect to MYSQL database in PHP with prepared statements

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql, database, pdo

I have recently learned about using PDO. I created a db class which could handle common actions like create, update, delete and select. Is this method a correct way to connect to the database using prepared statements?

```
<?php

class Db {

private $db_host = DB_HOST;
private $db_user = DB_USERNAME;
private $db_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
private $db_port = DB_PORT;
private $db_name = DB_DATABASE;
private $db_charset = DB_CHARSET;

private $dsn = "";
private $pdo = null;
private $stmt = null;
private $result = array();
private $conn = false;
private $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

public function __construct()
{
    if(!$this->conn) {
        try {
            $this->dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->db_host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name . ";charset=" . $this->db_charset . ";port=" . $this->db_port;
            $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->options);
            return $this->pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $err = "Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected function select($table, $rows = "*", $join = null, $join_side = null, $where = array(), $order = null, $limit = null) {
    if($this->tableExists($table)) {
        $sql = "SELECT $rows FROM $table";
        $paramsArray_where = null;

        if($join != null && $join_side != null)
            $sql .= " $join_side $join";

        if(!empty($where)) {
            $table_val_where = ":" . implode(',:', array_keys($where));
            // Create an array of new keys that contain : in front of them
            $table_key_where = explode(",", $table_val_where);
            // get array values
            $values_where = array_values($where);
            // combine key with their respective values
            $paramsArray_where = array_combine($table_key_where, $values_where);

            $args = array();
            foreach($where as $key=>$value)
                $args[] = "$key=:$key";
            
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' && ', $args);
        }

        if($order != null)
            $sql .= " ORDER BY $order";

        if($limit != null)
            $sql .= " LIMIT $limit";

        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        if($this->stmt->execute($paramsArray_where)) {
            $this->result = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected function insert($table, $params=array()) {
    if(!empty($params)) {
        if($this->tableExists($table)) {
            // Seperating $params key and values
            $table_cols = implode(',', array_keys($params));
            $table_val = ":" . implode(',:', array_keys($params));
            // Create an array of new keys that contain : in front of them
            $table_key = explode(",", $table_val);
            // get array values
            $values = array_values($params);
            // combine key with their respective values
            $paramsArray = array_combine($table_key, $values);
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($table_cols) VALUES ($table_val)";

            $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            if($this->stmt->execute($paramsArray))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected function update($table, $params=array(), $where=array()) {
    if(!empty($params)) {
        if($this->tableExists($table)) {
            $table_val = ":" . implode(',:', array_keys($params));
            // Create an array of new keys that contain : in front of them
            $table_key = explode(",", $table_val);
            // get array values
            $values = array_values($params);
            // combine key with their respective values
            $paramsArray = array_combine($table_key, $values);

            $args = array();
            foreach($params as $key=>$value)
                $args[] = "$key=:$key";

            $sql = "UPDATE $table SET " . implode(', ', $args);

            if(!empty($where)) {
                
                $table_val_where = ":" . implode(',:', array_keys($where));
                // Create an array of new keys that contain : in front of them
                $table_key_where = explode(",", $table_val_where);
                // get array values
                $values_where = array_values($where);
                // combine key with their respective values
                $paramsArray_where = array_combine($table_key_where, $values_where);

                $bind_params = array_merge($paramsArray, $paramsArray_where);

                $args = array();
                foreach($where as $key=>$value)
                    $args[] = "$key=:$key";
                
                $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' && ', $args);
            }else{
                $bind_params = $paramsArray;
            }

            $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            if($this->stmt->execute($bind_params))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected function delete($table, $where = array()) {
    if($this->tableExists($table)) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $table";
        $paramsArray_where = null;
        
        if(!empty($where)) {
            
            $table_val_where = ":" . implode(',:', array_keys($where));
            // Create an array of new keys that contain : in front of them
            $table_key_where = explode(",", $table_val_where);
            // get array values
            $values_where = array_values($where);
            // combine key with their respective values
            $paramsArray_where = array_combine($table_key_where, $values_where);

            $args = array();
            foreach($where as $key=>$value)
                $args[] = "$key=:$key";
            
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' && ', $args);

        }

        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        if($this->stmt->execute($paramsArray_where))
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}

private function tableExists($table) {
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $this->db_name . " LIKE '$table'";
    $this->stmt = $this->pdo->query($sql);
    if($this->stmt->execute()) {
        if($this->stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function getResult() {
    $result = $this->result;
    $this->result = array();
    return $result;
}

public function __destruct()
{
    if($this->conn) {
        $this->conn = false;
        $this->pdo = null;
        $this->dsn = "";
        $this->stmt = null;
        $this->result = array();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I have tested the above code and it works fine.

Comment: "Can Someone just review my code if this method is correct" Does it produce the correct output? It seems like you did test it. What are your real concerns?

Comment: @Tec FYI: Constructors don't `return` https://stackoverflow.com/q/6849572/2943403  Okay I see a lot of things to refine.  I'll wait to see if this question gets closed before I start an answer.

Comment: @Mast I just want to know that if this is the optimized and correct way of doing this database stuff.

Comment: There are indeed a lot of things to say about this code. Useful reading material could be this: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Do read on down the page, there are some interesting nuggets of knowledge in there.

Comment: What is `$join_side` meant to hold?  There is too much to critique with the little time I have.  I'll defer to other contributors.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for the Article. Would definately check it out!

Comment: @mickmackusa I just thought it would be needed for different types of join like inner join, left join, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sam's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269894) covers a lot of good points I am not going to repeat, but I will tell you more issues.

#### Private properties

What is the point in setting constants as private properties? What is the purpose of having all these config values as private properties if they are only used in the constructor? These values should come from a config file that is stored outside of [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

#### Catching PDO exception

You copied some code without understanding why. You catch an exception and do nothing with it, as a result shooting yourself in the leg. Either remove the `try-catch` entirely or throw a new exception in the catch block. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch

#### Use strict types

Use any types at all! All your parameters and return values should have types specified. If you are not doing this, I guarantee you, at some point you will pass invalid value to one of your methods.

#### Use early returns.

Instead of wrapping 20 lines in an `if` block, use the opposite of that condition and `return`. For example:

```
if (!$this->tableExists($table)) {
    return false;
}
```

#### Avoid empty()

Usage of `empty()` is an antipattern. You can use it if you think the variable might be empty or **undefined** but when you know the variable is defined you don't need it. Change `if (!empty($where))` to `if ($where)`.

#### Don't check for the return value of PDOStatement::execute()

What do you expect to receive from this method? You set PDO to exception mode so that function should never return false. That `if` statement is useless.

#### Usage of rowCount()

Generally, you should never need to use this method. Especially you do not need `if ($this->stmt->rowCount() > 0)`. `0` is false-ish and `rowCount()` should never return negative numbers. In this case, however, you can keep this method call, but reduce the whole return statement to a single line.

```
{
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $this->db_name . " LIKE '$table'";
    return $this->pdo->query($sql)->rowCount() > 0;
}
```

#### Destructor

Why, oh why? You are destroying the object and all your properties are private. Unless you go out of your way to leak one of these variables, that destructor is pointless. You are destroying all of this anyway when the object is destroyed!

Answer (score 4):

### Canonical advice from a helpful post

As was mentioned in a comment there is a post with helpful advice for classes like this:  [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) (written by [@YourCommonSense](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/101565/your-common-sense)). It recommends setting the exception mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` which appears to be the case with the code here. It also recommends:

> 1. Tell PHP to report ALL errors:
>
>    ```
>    error_reporting(E_ALL);
>    ```
> 2. On a development server just turn displaying errors on:
>
>    ```
>    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
>    ```
> 3. On a production server turn displaying errors off while logging errors on:
>
>    ```
>    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
>    ini_set('log_errors', 1);
>    ```

<sup>[1](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#errors)</sup>

It also recommends making the PDO connection [once and only once per PHP request](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection). The code above appears to attempt to only connect once but that is flawed - see the section on **Constructor Logic** below for more on that topic.

### Possibility for SQL injection

As I mentioned in [this review of a similar wrapper class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269798/120114) there is potential for SQL injection - likely from methods like `insert()` and `update()`.  That article from phpdelusions.net has an [entire post about how many update and insert methods are vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).

> "placeholders are used and data is safely bound, therefore our query is safe". Yes, the *data* is safe. But in fact, what does this code do is **taking user input and adding it directly to the query**. Yes, it's a `$key` variable. Which goes right into your query untreated.
>
> Which means you've got an injection. <sup>[2](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#helper)</sup>

While it is up to the calling code to provide fields to update, where conditions etc. this code cannot prevent calling code from passing input straight from the client side. As the article explains later on that one can attempt to make a whitelist of fields that can be updated but for this central code that doesn’t seem feasible. However using backtick delimiters will help but then delimiters inside the name need to be escaped

> As it was said before, escaping delimiters would help. Therefore, your first level of defense should be escaping delimiters (backticks) by doubling them. Assembling your query this way,
>
> ```
> $setStr .= "`".str_replace("`", "``", $key)."` = :".$key.",";
> ```
>
> you will get the injection eliminated.
> <sup>[2](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#escaping_backticks)</sup>

#### Constructor logic

As was mentioned in a comment constructors typically don't have a `return` statement, though [it is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099742/1575353).

It appears that the `$conn` property is not assigned in the constructor (only in the destructor), but that property doesn't seem to be doing much. The default value is `false` so this conditional in the constructor will always evaluate to `true`:

> ```
> if(!$this->conn) {
> ```

It might make more sense to check if `$this->pdo` is not `null` but in the constructor that seems pointless since the object is just being created.

#### Method visibility

It appears that the only public methods are the constructor, destructor and `getResult()`. Perhaps the intention is that subclasses should be defined in order to utilize the core CRUD methods but if that is not the case then consider making those methods have `public` visibility.

#### Conditionals

In method `tableExists()` the following lines exist towards the end:

> ```
> if($this->stmt->execute()) {
>        if($this->stmt->rowCount() > 0)
>            return true;
>    }
> ```

Those conditionals could be combined into a single line:

```
if($this->stmt->execute() && $this->stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        return true;
}
```

#### adding where conditions

A commonly accepted principle is the [**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle](https://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/). There are places where blocks of code are repeated - e.g. the following block appears to be repeated within `select()`, `update()`, `delete()`.

> ```
>         $args = array();
>         foreach($where as $key=>$value)
>             $args[] = "$key=:$key";
>         
>         $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' && ', $args);
> ```

It would be simpler to abstract that logic into a method instead of having it exist multiple times.

Because it is a loop that pushes into an array, it can be simplified using [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
   $args = array_map(function($key) {
        return  "$key = :{$key}"; 
    }, array_keys($where));
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" && ", $args);
```

And hopefully the server is running PHP 7.4 or later since [currently there is LTS for version 7.4+](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) can be used to simplify the mapping:

```
    $args = array_map(fn($key) => "$key = :{$key}", array_keys($where));
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" && ", $args);
```

To utilize the advice from the article on phpdelusions.net a method could be created to use delimeters on the field name and escape them within the name:

```
public static function sanitizeNameCondition($name)
{
    return "`" . str_replace("`", "``", $name) . "` = :" . $name;
}
```

Then that can be used with `array_map()`:

```
$args = array_map([$this, 'sanitizeNameCondition'], array_keys($where));
$sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" && ", $args);
```

And that method can be used for the fields to set also:

```
$args = array_map([$this, 'sanitizeNameCondition'], array_keys($params));
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET " . implode(', ', $args);
```